# Iterative algorithm with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, amazon-emr, distributed-computing

We have a use case where in a Spark job

- We iterate over partitions of an external table

  - Load data of this partition (almost same data vol in each partition)
  - Do transformation(self joins, no udfs) on the data
  - save data to an external location
  - repeat

In the process, we do not cache any dataframes.

We are seeing a steady increase in memory usage after each iteration. After some time the job exits with Out of heap memory error.

I am looking for some pointers that might help in debugging this issue.

The code looks very similar to this.

```
while(date < endDate) {
    val df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM tbl JOIN tbl2 ON tbl.date = '${date}' AND tbl2.date = '${date}'")
    df.write.partitionBy("date").mode("overwrite").("s3://bucket/path")
    date = increment(date)
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to iterate over each partition individually? Why don't you load everything, apply the transformations and partition the data during the writing process?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We are restricted on how many nodes in a cluster we can add. Hence it's not possible to load everything at once.

Answer (score 0):

So say we have data what is not possible to join in one job but could be split by date(**we don't have a logic based on intersection by date**). So how we will join it, we just a split data for different job what could be run in parallel here a example where quantity is a year:

```py
empty = EmtpyOperator(task_id = "sync")
for year in range(start_year,end_year)
    spark_submit = LivyOperator()#or other what u use
    spark_submit >> empty
```

```scala
    ...
    val yearProcessing = spark.conf.get("spark.start_interval.year")
    val dataSourceOne = spark.read.parquet(...).where(year(col("date")) === yearProcessing)
    val dataSourceTwo = spark.read.parquet(...).where(year(col("date")) === yearProcessing)
    dataSourceOne
        .join(dataSourceTwo, dataSourceOne("date") === dataSourceTwo("date"))
        .select(dataSourceOne.columns.map(s=>dataSourceOne(s).alias(s"do_$s")++dataSourceTwo.columns.map(s=>dataSourceTwo(s).alias(s"dt_$s"):_*)
        .write
        .mode("overwrite")
        .partitionBy("dt_date")
        .option("partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic")
        .parquet("path/to/dist")
```

That what i did in my scenario. There i also use quntity by day but in this case i wrote bash script, because Airflow didn't allow to render dag with 5*365 task.

Comment: - We are using the flag you mentioned.
I updated the code snippet to better represent the situation.
We can't whole table join because of the table size.

Comment: Okay, i have such as problem in production. Just split join by year, month wherever u can to split. Make while loop not in same code where u call a join, just move it upper. I wrote a DAG in airflow just to have a more control and shiny UI to see how it is going. But there is some restriction based on quantity date what u choice.